# find equation for parabola in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_0,z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$. Find equation for a parabola with $z_0$ the focus and directrix $|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|$.

By definition, the equation for parabola should be 
$$
|z-z_0|=\text{distance between focus and the directrix.}
$$

However, how to express the distance between $z_0$ and the directrix now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance of $z$ from the y axis is $|\Re {z}|$

Lets work in standard Cartesian, and then look for the complex analogue.

The distance of a point $(x,y)$ from a line $ax + by + c = 0$

$\frac {|ax+by - c|}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}$

What are $a,b,c?$

the point $\frac {z_1+z_2}{2}$ is on the line.

and $(z_2-z_1)$ is normal to the line.

$a  = \Re (z_2-z_1)\\ b = \Im (z_2-z_1)\\
 c = \frac 12 (|z_2|^2 - |z_1|^2)\\
 \sqrt {a^2+b^2} = |z_2-z_1|$

$ax + by = \Re (\bar zz_2-\bar zz_1)$

$|z - z_0| = \frac {|\Re (\bar zz_2-\bar zz_1) - \frac 12 (|z_2|^2 - |z_1|^2)|}{|z_2-z_1|}$

Comment: Why we can have $ax + by = \Re (zz_2-zz_1)$ now? Since $x+yi=z$, then we have $z(z_2-z_1)=(x+yi)(a+bi)=xa-by+(ay+bx)i$ which gives us $ax - by = \Re (zz_2-zz_1)$. Should we use the conjugate of $z$ instead?

Comment: You might be right about that...  $(\overline {z_2- z_1})$ would work, too.